# Phase plane analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following assignment:

Determine whether the origin is stable or unstable, a node, spiral, saddle or center.

a)
$$ 
A =
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
6 & 2  \\
2 & 3  
\end{array} } \right)
$$

So I will start to find the eigenvalues.
$$A-\lambda I=
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
6-\lambda & 2  \\
2 & 3-\lambda 
\end{array} } \right)
$$
$$\text{det}(A-\lambda I)=(6-\lambda)(3-\lambda)-4 =18-6\lambda-3\lambda+\lambda^2-4$$
$$\lambda^2-9\lambda+14$$
$$\text{the roots are} \ \ \lambda=2 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lambda=7$$
So I would say that the origin is unstable node because the eigenvalues are positive.

b)
$$ 
A =
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
-2 & 4  \\
-1 & 1  
\end{array} } \right)
$$
I will find the eigenvalues
$$A-\lambda I=
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
-2-\lambda & 4  \\
-1 & 1-\lambda 
\end{array} } \right)
$$
$$\text{det}(A-\lambda I)=(-2-\lambda)(1-\lambda)+4=-2+2\lambda-\lambda+\lambda^2+4$$
$$\lambda^2+\lambda+2$$
$$\text{the roots are} \ \ \lambda=\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \lambda=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2}$$
So the origin is stable spiral because the real part of the eigenvalues are negative

c)
$$A =
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & a  \\
0 & a  
\end{array} } \right), \ a\ne 0
$$

Am I correct in a) and b)? Can someone help me with c)?

Comment: (a),(b) looks fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HInt for (c), since $a \neq 0$. Consider the case $a>0$ and $a<0$. Assume $a \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a<0$, then we have:
$$\lambda_1 = -1, \lambda_2 = a<0 \Rightarrow \text{ stable node}$$

If $a>0$, then we have:
$$\lambda_1 = -1, \lambda_2 = a>0 \Rightarrow \text{ saddle point}$$